# MySQL insert using transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I have following structure on mysql database:

> [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc05e)

What I want to do is:

1. To select `DISTINCT industry` from `Company` table
2. To insert into `Industry` table first and get auto incremented ID
3. With this ID to insert again into IndustryTranslation table and set "language"="en"
4. To insert Company's id and newly generated Industry's id into `MapCompanyIndustry` table

I know that it's not possible with one statement. But definitely it's possible with transaction. Can't figure out how to achieve this result with one transaction.

Any suggestions?

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `Industry` (
  `id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `IndustryTranslation` (
  `industryID` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `confirmed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`industryID`,`language`),
  KEY `language` (`language`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Company` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageUri` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `countryID` int(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `industry` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `headquarters` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uri` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `countryID` (`countryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4004 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `MapCompanyIndustry` (
  `companyID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `industryID` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`companyID`,`industryID`),
  KEY `industryID` (`industryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Start transaction; insert/select/insert/etc; commit;

Comment: @jarlh more detailed?

Comment: @Drew please post more detailed answer. I'm new to transactions

Comment: Transactions is not the issue here. Don't think about them, just do what you need to do. But do start transaction before, and commit after.

Comment: I've assumed your question has nothing to do with Microsoft SQL Server and retagged it accordingly. Please take into account that each vendor implements its own SQL dialect, they aren't all the same thing!